# How can I add new component in jira via SOAP?

Tags: java, soap, jira

I would like to add a new component in a jira Project via Soap, but I don't found the appropriate method to do this.

this is an example of adding a component to an existing issue :

```
RemoteComponent component = new RemoteComponent();
component.setId("1000");
issue.setComponents(new RemoteComponent[] { component });
```

But in my case, I would like to add a new component, Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no `addComponent` or similar method in the [JiraSoapService](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html), so you simply can't do it.

I don't know why, but JiraSoapService is missing lots of features compared to the Jira web front end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://jiradev.blogspot.com/2011/08/adding-components-to-jira-automatically.html for a workaround

~Matt